# What happens if I load a nib w/o passing the file owner in the xib as the owner in -loadNibNamed: owner:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nib

I only just recently learned that the file owner to a xib does not have to be a `NSWindowController` or `NSViewController` (don't know why I thought that).

So I understand that this is the order things happen:

1. An object is instantiated (w/ MVC, the controller).  Outlet
   properties are not connected, and point to nil
2. The nib has to be initialized, with `-initWithNibNamed` (and will
   be loaded when the `view` or `window` is accessed) or w/
   `-loadNibNamed` (which will initialize then load the nib together)
3. The outlets are all connected once the nib is initialized
4. `-awakeFromNib` is called on the controller

But now what doesn't make sense to me, is why it even matters that I specify the owner of the nib in the `-loadNibNamed` call.

```
   BOOL effectsXibLoaded = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Effects"
                                                         owner:self.effectsController
                                               topLevelObjects:nil];
```

I say this because I imagine because we have specified in the `nib` who the file owner is-- and therefore when the `nib` is initialized, it should know who to connect it's outlets to right?

Or is specifying the `owner` in `-loadNibNamed` just a way to add another object to the `owners` list (if that's a thing?).  I imagine there can only be one owner who receives the `-awakeFromNib` call from one `nib`, but I'm not sure.

In other words, if I specify the `owner`, when the `nib` is waking, it will notify said `owner`, as well as the `owner` specified in the `xib`?

Also I am not confident in my understanding of the order of how things execute, so if I am in need in corrections please don't hesistate

Answer (score 0):

The owner in the xib is a class.

The owner in `loadNibNamed` is an instance.

There's some magic in `NSApplicationMain` where it figures out the app delegate class, creates an instance, makes that the owner of the main nib, and sets that instance as the application's delegate... but there's nothing here to indicate a instance of the class specified as File's Owner will be generated if you don't alloc init one first...